# HTML - embed pdf file from the dropbox with pdf viewer (online)

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, dropbox

I have a link to pdf file that located in the my Dropbox folder.
 For example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/gqo4etwy7nudtu2/JasperReports-Server-Visualize.js-Guide.pdf

By clicking on the link, I may download the file.
I want to embed the file on my site. I use the following code:

```
<iframe src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/gqo4etwy7nudtu2/JasperReports-Server-Visualize.js-Guide.pdf?preview" height="100%" width="100%">
This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/gqo4etwy7nudtu2/JasperReports-Server-Visualize.js-Guide.pdf?preview">Download PDF</a>
</iframe>
```

I tried to set two files, the link above and another one that I found on Google. 
The link above unable to embed, and it's opened for download, all the other files embedded successfully.

How can I embed pdf file from Dropbox?

Comment: This kind of link won't allow embedding because the `Content-Disposition` is `attachment`.

Comment: @Greg can I change that ?

Comment: No, that's controlled by the server, and Dropbox doesn't offer a way to configure it.

Comment: @Greg Any other solution?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123648/html-embed-pdf-file-from-the-dropbox-with-pdf-viewer-online ]

Answer (score 1):

Found the [Dropbox Embedder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/embedder) but not yet tested:

You need to create an account in the [App Console](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) and create an app to get the **app key**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="YOUR_APP_KEY"></script>
```

Then you embed a Dropbox PDF file with the anchor tag:

```
<a
  href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0bdwmkjmqld9l2/dbx-supporting-distributed-work.pdf?dl=0"
  class="dropbox-embed"
  data-height="300px"
  data-width="600px"
></a>
```

[More info here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/embedder).